# Replace value in text only nodes

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath, text, replace

I am currently doing a replace operation on certain text nodes in an XML file using `SelectNodes()` and defining each node that needs to be updated - which works fine. This is very tedious (multiple rows but with the same replace operations every time). I would like to perform the replace operation only the **TEXT** nodes within that file.

This is what I have at the moment:

```bsh
$path = "C:\Dump\TEST"
$Files = Get-Childitem -Path $path -File -Include test_file_1.xml -Name

foreach ($File in $Files) {
    $xml = [xml](Get-Content $path\$File)

    $xml.SelectNodes('//ContactDetailsRow/Notes') | ForEach-Object {
        $_.'#text' = $_.'#text'.Replace("\", "\\").Replace("`b", "\b")
    }
    $xml.SelectNodes('//AddressesRow/Notes') | ForEach-Object {
        $_.'#text' = $_.'#text'.Replace("\", "\\").Replace("`b", "\b")
    }

    $xml.Save("$path\$File")
}
```

I have tried to do it using xpath like this which is throwing an error.

```bsh
$path = "C:\Dump\TEST"
$Files = Get-Childitem -Path $path -File -Include test_file_1.xml -Name

foreach ($File in $Files) {
    $xml = [xml](Get-Content $path\$File)
    $xml.SelectNodes('//text()') | ForEach-Object {  
        $_.'#text' = $_.'#text'.Replace("\", "\\").Replace("`b", "\b")
    }
    $xml.Save("$path\$File")
}
```

The error is this

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Dump\test12.ps1:14 char:13
+             $_.'#text' = $_.'#text'.Replace("\", "\\").Replace("`b", "\b")
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

This is an example XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrganisationUnits>
  <OrganisationUnitsRow num="21">
    <OrganisationId>ORG1</OrganisationId>
    <OrganisationName>ORG 1 TEST</OrganisationName>
    <Addresses>
      <AddressesRow num="1">
        <AddressId>E41002</AddressId>
      </AddressesRow>
    </Addresses>
    <ContactDetails>
      <ContactDetailsRow num="1">
        <ContactValue>info@gmail.com</ContactValue>
        <StartDate>2000-03-11</StartDate>
        <Main>N</Main>
        <Notes>TEST \ NOTES</Notes>
      </ContactDetailsRow>
    </ContactDetails>
    <Sector>P</Sector>
    <SectorDesc>Private</SectorDesc>
  </OrganisationUnitsRow>
</OrganisationUnits>
```

Comment: `//text()` -> `//*[text()]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell can manage XML with native cmdlets built to help you do just what you're trying to do.

```
$path = "C:\Dump\TEST"
$Files = Get-Childitem -path $path -File -include test_file_1.xml -name

foreach ($File in $Files) 
{
    [xml]$MyXML = Get-Content $File.FullName -raw
    Select-Xml -XML $MyXML -XPath '//text()'|% {$_.Node.Value = $_.Node.Value -replace '\\','\\' -replace '`b','\b'}
    $MyXML.Save($File.FullName)
}
```